# Bussiness data catalog

Tags: bdc-model

   Is it possible to update data in SQL Server with BDC

Answer (score 2):

As you call it BDC and not BCS i take it you are using SharePoint 2007 (please update tags).

BDC for SP2007/MOSS is read only.

That being said Lightningtools do support update operations so you might consider the article below

http://www.lightningtools.com/bdc-meta-man/business-data-catalog-write-back.aspx

Comment: Not mentioned, but implied by Anders, is that in SharePoint 2010 the BCS (new version of BDC) does allow updates.